# Isolate page to turn off header

Tags: header-footer

I have headers on each page using `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` throughout my document, which I want to turn off on certain pages with large figures. If I use `\thispagestyle{empty}` it correctly removes the header, but only on a random page. I thought I could apply the effect to the correct page by putting `\newpage` right before my figure and then using `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but the result is still the same. Do I have to create a new `.tex` just for the figure or is there an easier way to do it?

In my `main.tex` document I have `\begin{document}`, and then `\pagestyle{fancy}`,
`\fancyfoot{}`,
`\lhead{\thepage}`,
`\rhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}`,followed by various `.tex` documents. Looking at a specific `.tex` document, I have a lot of text with graphics inserted as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hbox{\hspace{-15mm} \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{my-image}}
\caption{my caption}
\label{myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried putting `\newpage` followed by `\thispagestyle{empty}` right before the image, but it applies it to the wrong page. I also tried `\clearpage` as suggested in the comments but the same thing happened.

Comment: `\clearpage \thispagestyle{empty} \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`? Try `\clearpage` and let us know if it worked or not, failing that could you edit some code into your question please? It helps troubleshooting, you can use `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` instead of your graphics

Comment: @JamesT The same thing happened although I think it removed the header from a different page this time. Updated my question with some code, let me know if anything more is needed. I've always had this problem with images going to random pages but I have never known how to deal with it

Comment: You should put `[p]` after `\begin{figure}` if you want it to be on a float page, I cannot reproduce your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work (although we do not know your `\documentclass` or much else to trial and error solutions):

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For text

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \hbox{\hspace{-15mm} \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{my caption}
    \label{myfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-8]

\include{chapter1}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

The parts in `filecontents` are just an example of one of your `.tex` files that I created.

---

To put the page number on the `[p]` page use this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For text

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{floatp}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \hbox{\hspace{-15mm} \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{my caption}
    \label{myfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% ------------ Added
\fancypagestyle{floatp}{%redefining plain pagestyle
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}         % Page number in bottom right
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-8]

\include{chapter1}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Do you have any idea how I would put back the page number at the bottom of the page, which I had disabled with `\fancyfoot{}` , just for this page?

Comment: Yeah, see the edit :)

Answer (score 5):

What about `\floatpagestyle{empty}` and use only `[p]` for large floats?

See also `\rotfloatpagestyle` and `\thisfloatpagestyle`  in the manual of `floatpag` package.

Note also that `fancyhdr` provides
`\iffloatpage{`*value for float page*`}{`*value for other pages*`}`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatpag}\floatpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{foo1}\subsection{foo}\lipsum[1]
\section{foo}\subsection{foo}\lipsum[1]
\section{foo}\subsection{foo}\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[h]\includegraphics[]{example-image-9x16}\caption{foo}\end{figure}
\section{foo}\subsection{foo}\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[p]\centering\includegraphics[]{example-image-9x16}\caption{foo}\end{figure}
\section{foo}\subsection{foo}\lipsum[1]
\section{foo}\subsection{foo}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the directive `\pagestyle{empty}` to be issued after the page prior to the page holding the figure is shipped out.

- With a recent LaTeX release you can use the hook `shipout/after` for having carried out code right after having had LaTeX ship out some page. (According to the `\changes`-entries in **ltshipout.dtx** that hook was added in January 8, 2021.)
- You can use the package [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) for storing and retrieving the value of the so-called "absolute page number" of the page where LaTeX is placing the figure in question.
- Additionally you can define a macro `\CodeAfterShipoutOfAbsolutePage` where you can specify an absolute page number and some code so that directives are appended to the hook `shipout/after` for carrying out the code only after the shipping-out of the page whose absolute page number has the specified value.
- In the example below the absolute page number can be specified by having TeX do calculations which may involve accessing a zref-label. Therefore in the example below `\CodeAfterShipoutOfAbsolutePage` does not take only two arguments but takes three arguments, one of them denoting a comma-separated list of zlabels that must be defined for the specification of the absolute page number to work out. If one of those zlabels is not defined, as in any case is the case in the 1st compilation, the code won't be carried out, either.

  **!! Thus at least two compilations are needed for everything to match out. !!**

So syntax of `\CodeAfterShipoutOfAbsolutePage` is:

```latex
\CodeAfterShipoutOfAbsolutePage
  {<comma-list of zref-labels that must exist for the code to be carried out>%
    % Here you specify both those zref-labels that are needed for the
    % <expression for computing the absolute page number of the page after 
    % whose shipping-out code shall be carried out> to work out and probably
    % also those zref-labels that are needed for the <code to carry out after
    % the page has been shipped out> to work out.
  }%
  {<expression for computing the absolute page number of the page after 
    whose shipping-out code shall be carried out>}%
  {<code to carry out after the page has been shipped out>%
    % Be aware that you cannot use this for adding visible material
    % or glue to a page. You can use this only for doing abstract actions
    % like calculations or directives like `\thispagestyle{...}`.
  }%
```

Here comes a minimal working example.
In the example the hook `shipout/after` is used.
According to the `\changes`-entries in **ltshipout.dtx** that hook was added in January 8, 2021.
Thus the example definitely does not work out with LaTeX releases prior to January 8, 2021, but with such earlier LaTeX releases you don't get error-messages!
This is because assigning code to a hook which does not exist in the sense of its usage not being implemented doesn't trigger warning- or error-messages.
The example works out, e.g., with TeX Live 2022.
Thus it is compilable, e.g., with [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) if in Overleaf's menu TeX Live 2022 is selected.

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2021/01/08]
% (According to \changes-entry in ltshipout.dtx the hook
%  shipout/after  was added in January 8, 2021.)
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage[abspage]{zref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%...............................................................................
% Save the  value of abspage-counter to a zref-label:
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \saveabspage #1 {\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{abspage}}
%...............................................................................
% Obtain the saved abspage-counter-value from zref-label if possible, otherwise
% deliver -1:
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \getabspage #1 {\zref@extractdefault{#1}{abspage}{-1}}
%...............................................................................
% Map over comma-list #1 denoting zref-labels and execute code #2 in case all of
% them are defined, otherwise execute code #3; this is for doing calculations 
% with zref-labels which can only be done in case all of them are defined:
%...............................................................................
\cs_new:Npn \CheckWhetherAllZlabelsDefined #1 
  {
    \exp:w
      \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \mystuff_checkzlabel:nwnn
      \exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_i:nn
  }
\cs_new:Npn \mystuff_checkzlabel:nwnn #1#2 \exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_i:nn #3#4
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\getabspage{#1}}={-1}
      {#2 \exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_i:nn {#4}}
      {#2 \exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_i:nn {#3}}{#4}%
  }
%...............................................................................
% Map over comma-list denoting zref-labels and generate warning for each 
% undefined zref-label:
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \WarnForUndefinedZlabels #1
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1}\zref@refused
  }
%...............................................................................
% Provide code to execute on background-picture-environment of page whose
% absolute page number is to be specified:
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \CodeAfterShipoutOfAbsolutePage#1#2#3{ 
  % #1 = comma-list of zref-labels that must exist for the code (#3) to be 
  %      carried out.
  % #2 = expression for computing the absolute page number of the page 
  %      after whose shipout the code #3 shall be carried out:
  % #3 = code to carry out after shipping out the specified page
  \AddToHook{shipout/after}{
    \WarnForUndefinedZlabels{#1}
    \int_compare:nNnT {\CheckWhetherAllZlabelsDefined{#1}{#2}{-1}}
                      =
                      {\value{abspage}}
                      {#3}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headings}

\CodeAfterShipoutOfAbsolutePage{Some ABS label}%
                               {\getabspage{Some ABS label}-1}%
                               {\thispagestyle{empty}}%

\begin{document}
\section{Some headings}
\subsection{Some more headings}
\lipsum{1-2}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
\caption{Some figure}\saveabspage{Some ABS label}
\end{figure}
\lipsum{3-18}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(A drawback is that you can't use this for modifying the first page because there won't be a page prior to that after whose shipout things could be done.)